# PowerShell analog to "dir /a:d" (Win) or "ls -d */" (Bash)

Tags: powershell, scripting, directory

I simply want to list all of the directories under my current working directory, using PowerShell. This is easy from a Bash shell:

```
ls -d */
```

or cmd.exe in Windows:

```
dir /a:d
```

Using PowerShell however I cannot seem to be able to do it with a single command. Instead the only the I've found that works is:

```
ls | ? {$_Mode -like "d*"}
```

That seems way too wordy and involved, and I suspect that I don't need a separate Where clause there. The help for Get-ChildItem doesn't make it clear how to filter on Mode though. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: If you find this issue as annoying is I do, please vote on this on MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=308796

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works too:

```
ls | ?{$_.PsIsContainer}
```

There is no doubt that it is a little more wordy than bash or cmd.exe. You could certainly put a function and an alias in your profile if you wanted to reduce the verbosity. I'll see if I can find a way to use -filter too.

On further investigation, I don't believe there is a more terse way to do this short of creating your own function and alias. You could put this in your profile:

```
function Get-ChildContainer
{
    param(
            $root = "."
          )
    Get-ChildItem -path $root | Where-Object{$_.PsIsContainer}
}

New-Alias -Name gcc -value Get-ChildContainer -force
```

Then to ls the directories in a folder:

```
gcc C:\
```

This solution would be a little limited since it would not handle any fanciness like -Include, -Exclude, -Filter, -Recurse, etc. but you could easily add that to the function.

Actually, this is a rather naive solution, but hopefully it will head you in the right direction if you decide to pursue it. To be honest with you though I wouldn't bother. The extra verbosity in this one case is more than overcome by the overall greater flexibility of powershell in general in my personal opinion.

Comment: Ehh...I left my compiler at home, so no conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ls | ? {$_.PsIsContainer}
```

Comment: I guess I was too slow for EBGreen!

Comment: I guess speed isn't all that matters. :)

Comment: This can be simplified in PowerShell 3 to save keystrokes: ls | ? PsIsContainer

Answer (score 2):

```
dir -Exclude *.*
```

I find this easier to remember than

```
dir | ? {$_.PsIsContainer}
```

Plus, it is faster to type, as you can do -ex instead of -exclude or use tab to expand it.

Comment: This doesn't work when you have directories that have a dot e.g. `foo.bar`

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` or `ls -dir` for short. This has existed at least since PowerShell 3.0 according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 0):

You can check old post on PowerShell team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/03/13/dir-a-d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread because I'm trying to figure out how "FOR /D" works.  Well actually how to use the batch-command escape(%) with the /D option.

I read the above items with hope, to be honest they're all a lot more complex than the FOR command option -- If it worked of course.

---

**Using additional forms of for**

> If command extensions are enabled (that is, the default), the following additional forms of for are supported:

**Directories only**

> If set contains wildcards (* and ?), the specified command executes for each directory (instead of a set of files in a specified directory) that matches set. The syntax is:
>
> for /D {%% | %}variable in (set) do command [CommandLineOptions]

Answer (score 0):

Well, soon we will have to a make a class to simplify things and be typing commands like
dir -options {122b312aa3132-1313-131112f8111111} just so we can do the same as

dir/ad/od